# Algorithm for plotting a group of lines efficiently

Tags: algorithm

I found the following algorithms question online, but can't find any efficient solution.
It was asked at a Google Interview. The question goes like this:

Given a sequence of lines to be plotted(each line has start and end point),
give an algorithm that helps you to plot the lines in the least amount of time.
It is not necessary that a line has to be plotted from start point only.

There was one approach which treated each line as a node in the graph.
And the edge between 2 nodes is the distance between ending node of first line
and starting node of second line. After this, if we calculate Minimum Spanning Tree,
it will give the optimal answer.

But I am not sure if this gives optimal solution all the time since it assumes that
line is plotted in one direction only.

Can anyone provide a hint about how this kind of problem can be solved?

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by "plotting". In my mind, drawing lines consists in writing them to a raster, and then sending that raster to the frame buffer. If I do like this, the time required to plot the lines depends from the length of the lines, and the number of lines, but is independent from the order in which the lines are printed.
More mathematically speaking, you should provide a cost function `C(S)` that gives the cost of the solution S, and that you would like to minimize.

Comment: @Giulo - my guess is a pen plotter. The order of the lines becomes significant because of the time to move the pen (without drawing) from one lines end point to the next lines start point. Assuming "b/w" means "between", this is what the graph mentioned above stores in each edge, so the minimum spanning tree is choosing the least total between-lines non-drawing pen motion to draw that group of lines.

Comment: @Aman - I'm pretty sure the minimum spanning tree is based on *undirected* graphs. That means traversal in either direction is equally permitted. I'd be more concerned that in a tree, a vertex can have an odd number of edges leading out - see the [Seven Bridges of Königsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg#Euler.27s_analysis) problem for why. Sorry - I don't know what to do to fix it, except that maybe [Napalidon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18523742/180247) is correct about Dijkstra - this does after all sound like a route-finding problem.

Comment: @Giulo, Steve314 is right about definition of "plotting"

Comment: Can the plotter stop in the middle of a line and finish the rest of the line later? I'm pretty sure that I can construct examples where it would be optimal to do so (e.g. a short line near the midpoint of a much longer one).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Let's say no, i.e. if a plotter starts plotting a line
It will have to finish it before moving onto another.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming Steve314's interpretation of a pen plotter in the comment is correct (as stated by OP), then the problem is a certain generalization of the travelling salesman problem, which is known to be NP-complete.

Proof: if all lines have length 0, i.e., reduce to points, then the problem is: each point has to be touched by the pen and the total distance travelled by the pen has to be minimised. This is exactly the Euclidean travelling salesman problem.

So you should be looking for an approximation algorithm (you cannot find the optimal solution efficiently). Some of the [approximation algorithms for the Euclidean TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms) are based on a miminum spanning tree and can be modified to solve your problem. It might also be possible to prove that the resulting algorithm will give you a path that is no longer than X (=two?) times the length of the optimal path.

**EDIT**: Here's a complete example adapted from the "simplest" metric TSP approximate solution algorithm in Wikipedia

1. Interpret the lines you want to draw as edges of an undirected (possibly disconnected) graph whose vertices are the specified endpoints
2. Complete to a minimal connected (spanning) graph that contains the wanted edges (using Prim's algorithm)
3. Convert to directed graph and find an [Eulerian circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)

This should give you a solution (follow the path drawing edges as appropriate) that is at most twice as long as the optimal path. It can be further optimized in many ways, for example, by taking a shortcut and skipping a vertex in the path whenever the next edge does not need to be drawn (again or at all).

Comment: Well actually, not exactly TSP - you don't have to go back to the start. It's not obvious to me how you could elegantly remove that requirement from TSP (just deleting the longest edge from the TSP solution doesn't result in an optimal solution to *this* problem)

Comment: You may be right, but both problems are NP-hard and can be solved approximately using similar algorithms.

Comment: @harold, this answer shows that if you can solve this problem efficiently then you can solve TSP efficiently, therefore this problem is at least as hard as TSP.

Answer (score 1):

For a minimum spanning tree you will have to use Djikstra's algorithm which will pick a shortest path and compare it to all others connected to the same node recursively until all the nodes are processed. Actually I just reread you question and since your path doesn't have to start at a certain point you can use Prim's which has the same idea as above but starts at any node. Both use a priority queue which allows for a breadth first search.

Comment: Have you verified this solves the problem?  I might be mistaken but seem to recall the stated problem being NP-complete

Comment: +1 because I think you're right to mention Dijkstra. Although I'm far from certain, though, I think more is involved. The choice of start position isn't a problem, though - just add an artificial start vertex with zero-weighted edges to all the real vertices.

Comment: @jwpat7 - NP-complete doesn't mean it can't be solved. It (informally) means that it'll be insanely slow for large instances of the problem. Even if this is travelling salesman in disguise (I'm not sure), I guess it can be solved in reasonable time for reasonable-sized instances of the problem. Maybe exactly, or if all else fails, at least approximately.

Comment: @Steve314, if it's NP-complete, then neither Djikstra's nor Prim's algorithm is likely to be of use.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty nasty problem. It's a Shortest Hamiltonian Path, but you have a *ton* of edges (all edges (u, v) where u is the endpoint of some line and v is the startpoint of a different line), and the distances aren't symmetrical. The elegant ZDD-based way described in TAOCP 4A doesn't really apply I think - it would get swamped in all those edges.

Here's an idea (not optimal, but it seems like a reasonably good idea anyway), borrowing from TSP:

```
For every line s
    Schedule = empty sequence
    For every line n
        insert n in the optimal position in Schedule
    Apply 2-opt (see TSP) to the Schedule
Take the best Schedule.
```

Be super careful with that 2-opt. It is often described for the symmetric-distances case, which lets you optimize the "change in distance" calculation. You can't do there here.

Here's an other idea, borrowing heavily from TSP:

Solve a ton of ILP problems. For every node `s` and `t` (not equal):

- a boolean variable for every edge.
- weights are the lengths of those edges.
- every node `n` that isn't `s` or `t` gives a constraint of the form "sum of all edges adjacent to `n` == 2"
- for nodes `s` and `t`, that sum is instead equal to 1
- lazily add constraints that the entire thing must be a single connected component, that is:

  - detect connected components. If there is 1, this is a solution.
  - if there is more than 1, for every connected component:
  - if it contains `s` or `t`, add the constraint that the sum of all edges adjacent to that connected component must be 1.
  - otherwise, that sum must be 2.

Take the best of all those solutions. It could take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand your question. One approach could be to start with your drawing area, say a 640X480 image. Then for each position in the image, you check whether the pixel (x,y) lies on at least one line (you only need to satisfy one line using the line equation and the some suitable value for epsilon), if so, you output a 1 else a 0. All lines are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Use a disjoint-set data structure. It solves the minimum spanning tree as soon as you do the union of the sets. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure